# how to iteratively pick out one attribute in an object, and stack the rest attributes into an array, Python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, object

I have an object with a, b, c, d four attributes. Each attribute is a vector.
I want to pick one attribute out and assemble the rest attributes into an 2-dimensional array. And do it for every attribute.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

class Obj:
    def __init__(self, a, b, c, d):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d

b = np.array([1,1,1,1,1])
a = 0*b
c = 2*b
d = 3*b

obj1 = Obj(a, b, c, d)

# take attribute a for example
pick = obj1.a
x = np.column_stack((obj1.b, obj1.c, obj1.d))
# then pick attribute b, c, and d, one at a time, and assemble the rest.
```

Is there a way to iterate over all attributes? Because in real case, there may be 40 attributes.

Thanks

Comment: is `b,c,d` same as `d,c,b` for your `stack` operation?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, thanks for responding. In my practical case, it depends. Some situation, the sequence matters, sometimes it doesn't.